# Guidance for deploying Redis Cache for Kubernetes Microservices

Tags: kubernetes, caching, redis, kubernetes-pod, redis-cache

I am looking to implement Redis Cache for a number of web applications in Kubernetes, but am not sure how exactly to architect the Redis Cache part.

I was thinking that if I have 5 replicas of my application, they could all use a single Redis Cache in a separate pod, as I wanted to avoid using a sidecar container for each application pod. Then for each application, they have their own Redis Cache Deployment in Kubernetes, and the application connects to this (by a service I guess).

Does this sound like a suitable plan?
How does the application talk to the Redis Cache pod, do I need to expose it via a Service?
I've seen that you should co-locate your Redis Cache and Application on the same node, is this a concern, and is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With [helm](https://helm.sh/) you can easily install redis on your cluster using the [bitnami chart](https://github.com/bitnami/charts/tree/main/bitnami/redis).
Or i prefer to install a [redis](https://github.com/ot-container-kit/redis-operator) [operator](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/extend-kubernetes/operator/) an let it do the magic.

Either way, you can install one or multiple redis on your kubernetes cluster and they will be accessible through a kubernetes service at something like `http://my-redis-service.cool-namespace.svc.cluster.local:6379`.

There is no need to co-host redis on the same node, that's where kubernetes does the work.

Comment: Thank you, this is similar to the approach I was looking into to.